# Where can I find the minified version of the jQuery color plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The repository is [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

```
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color
```

And the example use shows jquery.color.min.js

However I cannot find the file anywhere in the repository

Comment: Oops, I just answered thinking you were looking for jQuery itself. I should read questions more carefully! `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, hope this helps, cheers!

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/31/jquery-color-v2-beta-1-released/

http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.0b1.min.js

http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.0b1.js

*further quote*

> ```
> >     Back in 2007 we released the jQuery Color Plugin, and it has been providing you with color-based animations ever since. We are now
>  preparing a second version of this plugin which adds an API, RGBA,
> > HSLA, and many other features. It is time for a beta! The repository
> > for this plugin can be found at github.com/jquery/jquery-color.  There
> > are also uncompressed and minified versions available on
> > code.jquery.com.
> ```

Comment: Comment by nkint : Update http://blog.jquery.com/2012/11/23/jquery-color-2-1-1-released/